# how to convert 1012 (decimal) to 100C (hexadecimal)

Tags: hex, decimal

When I try to convert the decimal value 1012 to hexadecimal, I get the value 3F4. However, in the class the teacher got the value 100C.

Could anyone tell me how that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 12 in hexadecimal is C...
So 1 = 1, 0 = 0, 12 = C
1 0 12 = 1 0 0xC

That's the only way I can see it being possible.

Comment: Oh I see now! I thought the first 1 and 0 of 1012 are like 1000 and have to be converted also. In the end, 12 is the only one to be converted into C.

Answer (score 0):

Well 100C if I am not wrong, is not 1012. 100C is:

1 * (16^3) + 12 * (16^0) = (4096 + 12) = 4108

Are you sure that your teacher gave that result?

Comment: Yes that's why I couldn't figure out how he made that conversion.
In fact, he was showing us the location of four integers in the memory of a IA-32 processor. The first one (int) was located at 1000 (decimal). He said that the fourth one has to be located at 1012, which will be 100C in hex.